# How would I grab the date from a data frame full of these strings?

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

I need to take these and convert each date to a date time object. I have 500 columns of this, but need to extract the date.

'''
0      Reviewed in the United States on December 30, ...

1       Reviewed in the United States on August 28, 2019

2      Reviewed in the United States on February 6, 2020

3      Reviewed in the United States on November 6, 2019

4         Reviewed in the United States on March 6, 2020
'''

Comment: What have you tried so far? have you looked up any module for parsing date times from string?

Answer (score 0):

If you isolate the part of a line that represents a date, you can use datetime.datetime.strptime() with a format string. In your example, the date string is just the last three words:

```
from datetime import datetime

raw_line = '1 Reviewed in the United States on August 28, 2019'
date_str = " ".join(raw_line.split()[-3:])
parsed_date = datetime.strptime(date_str, '%B %d, %Y')
```

If there's more variation in what each line looks like, you can import the re module and write a Regex to isolate the date string.